# Xubuntu Mail Watcher (XFCE Plugin) Won't Connect To IMAP

Tags: xubuntu, mail, imap, xfce-panel

I am trying to get the XFCE Mail Watcher panel plugin to check my IMAP mail, but it won't connect to my server. I have entered the details correctly -- they're exactly the same as those I use in Thunderbird -- but nothing!

When I go to select the "New mail folders..." it returns with "Failed to get folder list". If I change my username from `name@domain` to `name`, I still get this error, but it takes a few seconds longer to appear. Nothing shows up in the log.

If it makes a difference, my mail is hosted by Microsoft, in some way. Like I say, I can access it through Thurderbird using the IMAP credentials; but I have the Exchange 2010 web app, if I use webmail. Could this be the problem? (Thunderbird often complains with "Command Error. 12" with what it gets back from the server, but carries on regardless.)

Answer (score 3):

Try installing a plug-in for Thunderbird called **Firetray**, its a decent workaround to avoid this Xubuntu 12.10 "Bug".

Comment: +1, but it's far from ideal...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable "less secure app" setting on your gmail account for this to work

https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps